# React Router: Cannot Access Private Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I did not get the help I was looking for. I have added more information to my code below. I have a protected route that can only be accessed if the user has logged in and then isAuthenticated set to true. The issue I am having is, even after successfully logging in and being authenticated, I am getting redirected to login page. In my redux reducer file below, the isAuthenticated state is set to null by default. The weird part is that if I set isAuthenticated default value to true and then login successfully, I can access the protected route. However, when isAuthenticated is set to null, I am unable to access the protected route even if I successfully login. Would greatly appreciate it if someone can help. Thank you.

//Load user action file

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) =>{

  dispatch({type: USER_LOADING});
  const token = getState().auth.token; 
 
  const config = {
    headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }

if(token){
  config.headers['x-authorization'] = token;
}

  axios.get('/api/user/', config)
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    }))
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR
      });
    });
  };
```

//Redux Reducer File

```
import{
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOADING,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  isLoading: false,
  user: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case USER_LOADING:
      return{
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case USER_LOADED:
      return{
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        user: action.payload
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
    return{
      ...state,
      ...action.payload,
      isAuthenticated: true,
      isLoading: false
    };
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
      return{
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false,
        user: null
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

//ProtectedRoute file

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
})=>(
  <Route {...rest} component={(props) =>(
    isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ):(
      <Redirect to="/login"/>
    )
  )}/>

)

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
}
const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProtectedRoute)
```

//App.js File

```
class App extends Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }
  render(){
  return(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/userfeed" component={UserFeed}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
  </Provider>

);
}
};

export default App;
```

Comment: try making isAuthenticated:false instead of null in initial state,  I guess ternary operator in private route is giving some issue

Comment: Why not simply render a `Route` or `Redirect`, spread the "component" prop into `Route`, i.e. `ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, ...rest}) => isAuthenticated ? <Route {...rest} /> : <Redirect to"/login" />`? Also, why does your reducer issue a side-effect of mutating local storage? Reducers should be pure functions.

Comment: I've already tried that but it still redirects me to login. I suspect it has to something with loadUser when it dispatches in App.js file because when user is loading, isAuthenticated is set to null and maybe the protected route file is getting the value of isAuthenticaed when user is loading instead of the value from user loaded.

Comment: Ah, maybe you need an additional rendering branch in the private route to "wait" for any pending states to resolve. In other words, show a spinner or render null if `isLoading` is true.

Comment: Drew, can you give me an example?

Comment: What I do in my current project is that if not logged in, render LoginPage, otherwise, render the main components.

`if (loggedIn) {return <Login />} else {return <WhatEver />}`.

Not sure if `component={(props) =>( isAuthenticated ? ` works as expected. If you want to do this way, maybe you can try HOC. It's slightly different from what you wrote https://gist.github.com/197291/2b462f37433ead13a17cc2b93bbc2e33